# Why some div content is missing from ZoneTemplate in asp.net webpart?

Tags: asp.net, css, web-parts

Here is my code:

```
<asp:WebPartZone ID="Zone1" runat="server" Width="100%" PartChromeType="None" Padding="0" PartStyle-CssClass="NoPadding"
                PartStyle-BackColor="Transparent" BackColor="Transparent" PartChromeStyle-BackColor="Transparent">
                <PartStyle BackColor="Transparent"></PartStyle>
                <CloseVerb Visible="false" />
                <MinimizeVerb Visible="false" />
                <ZoneTemplate>
                    <div class="demo">
                        <p>Procedure Queues</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="demoBottom">
                        <div class="divPortletContent">
                        <br />
                        <asp:DataList ID="dlProcedureQueues" runat="server" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="lbProcedureQueues" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("site_nm") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("site_url") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ZoneTemplate>
            </asp:WebPartZone>
```

The text from `<div class="demo"><p>Procedure Queues</p></div>` is miising and it works if I put it outside of webpart.  Also, I am loosing all the css styles when placed inside webpart's ZoneTemplate.

Any ideas??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some reason, ZoneTemplate tag ignores all plain html and renders only asp.net controls.  If I convert all content from this template to a page control(ascx) and call it from template, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.  From what I found out, ZoneTemplate only considers the asp controls (including user controls) as web parts and ignores all the html.